# Galilean invariance of Newton's universal gravitation law

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, inertial-frames, galilean-relativity

So, I was reviewing special relativity and this question came across: How can one prove that Newton's universal law of gravitation is invariant under transformations of the galilean group?

As far as I know, one should take the law
$$m\frac{\partial ^2 \vec{x}}{\partial t^2}=-G\frac{Mm}{|\vec{x}|^2}\frac{\vec x}{|\vec x|}$$
and then apply on $\vec{x}$ a transformation of the galilean group as in:
$$\vec{x} \rightarrow \vec{x}' = t\vec{v} + R\vec{x} + \vec{d}$$
Where $\vec{d}$ is the displacement vector, $\vec{v}$ is the speed of the new reference system in regard to that in rest and R is a rotation matrix. On the other hand, time must transform as:
$$t \rightarrow t'=t+s$$
Where $s$ is a real number.

On the lefthand side of the equation, it seems easy to apply, since the time derivative doesn't change and eliminates the parts with $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{d}$, but I can't figure out how to proceed on the righthand side of it... Any ideas on how could I prove that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the misleading part is that $\vec{x}$ on the right hand side is the *relative* position of the two masses $m$ and $M$ so it actually reads

$$\vec{x}=\vec{x}_m-\vec{x}_M$$
and Newton's equation would read

$$m\partial_t^2\vec{x_m}  = -G{mM \over |x|^3}\vec{x} $$
(and the same for $x_M$ on the LHS for the other mass)

To transform $\vec{x}$ you need to transform $\vec{x}_m$ and $\vec{x}_M$ separately as

$$\vec{x}_m'=t\vec{v}+\vec{d}+R\vec{x}_m$$
and
$$\vec{x}_M'=t\vec{v}+\vec{d}+R\vec{x}_M$$

and then find the new relative position, so that now
$$\vec{x}'=\vec{x}_m'-\vec{x}_M'=R(\vec{x}_m-\vec{x}_M)=R\vec{x}$$

because $R$ is the rotation matrix, you are basically just rotating the relative positions vector, so $|x'|=|x|$ i.e. the magnitude does not change (its just a rotation).

[The following part contains a bit of hand-waving about rotation matrices and relative positions - but the result should be correct]

On the other hand, $\vec{x'}$ now points in a different direction defined by $R$ but you also have $R$ being applied on the left hand side so that  (using the fact that as you said the derivative does not change) and applying it in the case of $\vec{x}_m$ (is the same for $M$):

$$\partial_t^2\vec{x_m}'=\partial_t^2R\vec{x_m}=R\partial_t^2\vec{x_m}$$
as the rotation is constant - it basically just rotates the derivative too - so you get

$$mR\partial_t^2\vec{x_m} = -G{mM \over |x|^3}R\vec{x}$$
which you might rewrite as
$$R  \left(m\partial_t^2\vec{x_m} \right) = R \left(-G{mM \over |x|^3}\vec{x} \right)$$

which is exactly the same as before minus a rotation of the reference frame, which acts on both sides so the equation is formally the same as before.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, the way that you have stated it, the law seems like it is *not* invariant under Galilean transformations!

Remember that the Universal Law of Gravitation holds between **two** particles that are interacting with each other. For convenience, one of them (say $M$) is usually taken to be at the origin, and therefore the force exerted by it on another mass $m$ is supposed to be (in one dimension): $$m \frac{\text{d}^2\mathbf{x}}{\text{d}t^2} = - \frac{G M m}{x^2}\hat{\mathbf{x}}.$$

The reason that your formulation looks like it's not invariant is because you have forgotten the second mass in the problem! As a result, you are applying the transformation to one mass, while the other stays at the origin. This is not a Galilean boost, you're just giving one mass a velocity $v$!

Of course the more general form is when the two masses (say, $m_1$ and $m_2$) are at positions $x_1$ and $x_2$, respectively, in which case the force on mass "2" for example would be:

$$m_2 \frac{\text{d}^2\mathbf{x}_2}{\text{d}t^2} = - \frac{G m_1 m_2}{(x_1 - x_2)^2}\hat{\mathbf{x}}_{12},$$

where $\hat{\mathbf{x}}_{12}$ is the vector directed from mass 1 to mass 2.

You should now be able to show that under a Galilean transformation, $x_1$ and $x_2$ transform in such a way as to keep $|x_1 - x_2|$ constant.